# Подмена имени класса на числовое в Json

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

Столкнулся с проблемой при работе Json.

Ситуация следующая:

При выполнении действия отправляется Json пакет, который содержит следующую часть:

```
..."test1": {
    "test2": {
            "**2020**": {
                "test3":...
```

Стоит задача сделать автотест на это.

Класс с именем 2020 создать невозможно.

И собственно вопрос: как можно сделать так, чтобы при отправке запроса (Rest Assured) данный класс принимал имя "2020"?

Рассматривал вариант данный кусок сделать строкой, но поскольку вся остальная часть является объектам, то корректно склеить/засетить не удается.

Comment: По идее имя класса может быть любым. Важно только имя поля. А на него при сериализации/десериализации можно влиять через аннотации библиотек для JSON  типа Jackson, Moshi, Gson

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, всё получилось!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее имя класса может быть любым. Важно только имя поля. А на него при сериализации/десериализации можно влиять через аннотации библиотек для JSON типа `Jackson`, `Moshi`, `Gson`

Comment: Удалось с помощью аннотации Gson'a @SerializedName("2020"), что указывается над самой переменной, вот пример:  @SerializedName("2020")
    private Test2020 test2020;